Clang++ issue in linkling std libraries
I'm trying to build a program using clang++, on a Ubuntu 22.04 PC.

clang version: Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
gcc version 11.4.0

The SW compiles and links fine using g++ with the following command line:
   g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -Wno-deprecated-declarations -ggdb -O0 -g3 -O0 --coverage -Isrc/cscs -Isrc/include -Ilibraries/swap32/EC/debian/include -Ilibraries/zmq/EC/debian/include -Ilibraries/liquid_dsp/EC/debian/include -Xlinker -Map=telemachus.map   bin/file1.o  bin/file2.o  bin/file3.o -o bin/a.out -Llibraries/zmq/EC/debian -l:libzmq.a -Llibraries/swap32/EC/debian -l:libswap32.a -Llibraries/liquid_dsp/EC/debian/lib -l:libliquid.a -lpthread -lstdc++fs

But link fails with clangd++ when using this command line.
   clang++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -Wno-deprecated-declarations -ggdb -O0 -g3 -O0 --coverage -Isrc/cscs -Isrc/include -Ilibraries/swap32/EC/debian/include -Ilibraries/zmq/EC/debian/include -Ilibraries/liquid_dsp/EC/debian/include -stdlib=libc++ -fsanitize=address   bin/file1.o  bin/file2.o  bin/file3.o  -o bin/a.out -Llibraries/zmq/EC/debian -l:libzmq.a -Llibraries/swap32/EC/debian -l:libswap32.a -Llibraries/liquid_dsp/EC/debian/lib -l:libliquid.a -lpthread

Error messages

undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char,
undefined reference to `vtable for std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits >'

The command lines differ because:

I had to remove any reference to stdc++fs when building with clang++
I added the option -fsanitize=address (this is why I want to use clang++)
I added option -stdlib=libc++, otherwise the code do not build

I do not understand why, when building with clang++ it seems I didn't link the libraries, that are visible when using the g++.
Any help will be appreciated.
Giovanni

Are all of your code and libraries built using libc++? If some are built with libstdc++ that might be the cause of your problem. Please show a [mre]. Note that GCC supports address sanitizer too since version 4.8

Unrelated: 1) You should remove linking with stdc++fs when compiling with gcc 11.4 too. It's not needed since gcc 9 and it's an empty library since then. 2) -fsanitize=address works fine in gcc too.

note that std::__cxx11::basic_string is from the c++11 version of libstdc++, libc++ uses std::__1::basic_string


Did you only add -stdlib=libc++ when linking, and forgot to add it when compiling? 2. It shouldn't be necessary in the first place, make sure you have both gcc and g++ installed (Clang sometimes get confused if the latest gcc version you have is newer than your latest g++, I think?). 3. GCC has -fsanitize=address too, I believe?


First, thank you all.
@TedLyngmo I didn't know that even g++ supports address sanitizer, thank you for providing me info also about the stdc++fs.

Thank you @AlanBirtles I think the issue is in fact related to the different library. If I remove the
-stdlib=libc++ section, it doesn't compile, but as stated by you, it seems the other linked libraries have been built using libstdc++. i will further investigate. When understood I will provide feedback

Sounds like a better question for you to ask is why doesn't it compile with libstdc++, if you show the error message we can help
